# Magento Tries to Load from Old Development Directory after Changing Name

Tags: error, development

I had a working development instance (1.9.0.1) running on a subfolder "test" of my production instance. After I changed the name of the "test" folder to "development", Magento still attempts to load files from the test directory, which no longer exists. I updated both base urls in core_config_data. I cleared var/cache and var/session. I cleared the browser cache. I tested on another machine. I can't think of anything else to do. Here is the error when I go to mysite.com/development in the browser:

> Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mysite/public_html/test/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/mysite/public_html/test/app/code/local:/home/mysite/public_html/test/app/code/community:/home/mysite/public_html/test/app/code/core:/home/mysite/public_html/test/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mysite/public_html/test/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mysite/public_html/test/app/Mage.php on line 51
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/mysite/public_html/test/app/code/local:/home/mysite/public_html/test/app/code/community:/home/mysite/public_html/test/app/code/core:/home/mysite/public_html/test/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mysite/public_html/test/app/Mage.php on line 51
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/mysite/public_html/test/app/Mage.php on line 54

Comment: try to readd  Mage folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the reason, but the issue seems to have been caused by the .htaccess password on the development directory. Although there did not appear to be a problem with it, when I deleted directory protection and re-created it from cPanel, the above issue was resolved.